# Any reason why search result lists only one entry?

Tags: search

I'm wondering why I only get one result in my search.

My search query is this:
http://www.norwegianfashion.no/?s=oslo+fashion+week

If I search google, you'll see I got plenty of hits:
http://www.google.no/search?hl=en&client=opera&hs=GTw&rls=en-GB&q=oslo+fashion+week+site%3Awww.norwegianfashion.no&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

On my local computer I looked in the query log and I see this:

```
       29 Query SELECT option_name, option_value FROM nfwp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes'
       29 Query SELECT option_value FROM nfwp_options WHERE option_name = 'akismet_comment_nonce' LIMIT 1
       29 Query SELECT * FROM nfwp_users WHERE user_login = 'admin'
       29 Query SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM nfwp_usermeta WHERE user_id IN (1)
       29 Query SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  nfwp_posts.* FROM nfwp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (((nfwp_posts.post_title LIKE '%oslo%') OR (nfwp_posts.post_content LIKE '%oslo%')) AND ((nfwp_posts.post_title LIKE '%fashion%') OR (nfwp_posts.post_content LIKE '%fashion%')) AND ((nfwp_posts.post_title LIKE '%week%') OR (nfwp_posts.post_content LIKE '%week%')) OR (nfwp_posts.post_title LIKE '%oslo fashion week%') OR (nfwp_posts.post_content LIKE '%oslo fashion week%'))  AND nfwp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (nfwp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR nfwp_posts.post_author = 1 AND nfwp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY nfwp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
       29 Query SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
       29 Query SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM nfwp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (4139,4135,4130,4129,3831,4126,3750,2564,3667,3573)
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN nfwp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('post_tag') AND tr.object_id IN (4139) ORDER BY t.name ASC
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'nav_menu' AND t.term_id = '0' LIMIT 1
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'nav_menu' AND t.slug = 'quick-menu' LIMIT 1
       29 Query SELECT tr.object_id FROM nfwp_term_relationships AS tr INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('nav_menu') AND tt.term_id IN ('997') ORDER BY tr.object_id ASC
       29 Query SELECT   nfwp_posts.* FROM nfwp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND nfwp_posts.ID IN (4309) AND nfwp_posts.post_type = 'nav_menu_item' AND (nfwp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY menu_order ASC
       29 Query SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM nfwp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (4309)
       29 Query SELECT   nfwp_posts.* FROM nfwp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND nfwp_posts.ID IN (2) AND nfwp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND (nfwp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY nfwp_posts.post_date DESC
       29 Query SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM nfwp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (2)
       29 Query SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  nfwp_posts.* FROM nfwp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (((nfwp_posts.post_title LIKE '%oslo%20fashion%20week%') OR (nfwp_posts.post_content LIKE '%oslo%20fashion%20week%')))  AND nfwp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (nfwp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR nfwp_posts.post_author = 1 AND nfwp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY nfwp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
       29 Query SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'nav_menu' AND t.term_id = '0' LIMIT 1
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'nav_menu' AND t.slug = 'main-menu' LIMIT 1
       29 Query SELECT tr.object_id FROM nfwp_term_relationships AS tr INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('nav_menu') AND tt.term_id IN ('939') ORDER BY tr.object_id ASC
       29 Query SELECT   nfwp_posts.* FROM nfwp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND nfwp_posts.ID IN (3729,3731,3732,3733,3734,3735) AND nfwp_posts.post_type = 'nav_menu_item' AND (nfwp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY menu_order ASC
       29 Query SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM nfwp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (3729,3734,3733,3732,3731,3735)
       29 Query SELECT   nfwp_posts.* FROM nfwp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND nfwp_posts.ID IN (30,31,786,3365,7) AND nfwp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND (nfwp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY nfwp_posts.post_date DESC
       29 Query SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM nfwp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (3365,786,31,30,7)
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN nfwp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND tr.object_id IN (4139) ORDER BY t.name ASC
       29 Query SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  nfwp_posts.* FROM nfwp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND nfwp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (nfwp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY nfwp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5
       29 Query SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.*, tr.object_id FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN nfwp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category', 'post_tag') AND tr.object_id IN (4329, 4318, 4313, 4303, 4277) ORDER BY t.name ASC
       29 Query SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM nfwp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (4329,4318,4313,4303,4277)
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category' AND t.term_id = '998' LIMIT 1
       29 Query SELECT * FROM nfwp_users WHERE ID = 31 LIMIT 1
       29 Query SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM nfwp_usermeta WHERE user_id IN (31)
       29 Query SELECT * FROM nfwp_comments WHERE  comment_approved = '1' ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT 5
       29 Query SELECT * FROM nfwp_posts WHERE ID = 1154 LIMIT 1
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN nfwp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND tr.object_id IN (1154) ORDER BY t.name ASC
       29 Query SELECT * FROM nfwp_posts WHERE ID = 1684 LIMIT 1
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN nfwp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND tr.object_id IN (1684) ORDER BY t.name ASC
       29 Query SELECT * FROM nfwp_posts WHERE ID = 3432 LIMIT 1
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN nfwp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND tr.object_id IN (3432) ORDER BY t.name ASC
       29 Query SELECT * FROM nfwp_posts WHERE ID = 4138 LIMIT 1
       29 Query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM nfwp_terms AS t INNER JOIN nfwp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN nfwp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND tr.object_id IN (4138) ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

You can see that it finds several articles `(3729,3731,3732,3733,3734,3735)`.
I also see a lot of `LIMIT 1` in these queries. IS that correct?

Any ideas why I'm only getting one result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What template does search page use? It is either generic `index.php` or specialized `search.php`. What does Loop in that template look like?

I suspect this might be Loop issue that is set to only dislpay single post, instead of iterating all of them.

Comment: You are right. I use `search.php` taken from the default theme. A closer look I see that it is using ` get_template_part( 'loop', 'search' );`. I'm not used to this new feature in WP, so I over looked it. Thanks :)